# How to add new call as conference PJSIP with siphon

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whats  my project  .

1. voice calling .

Whats  library in my project .

1. Asterisk server (version 11.0)
2. pjsip 2.5.1
3. siphon for UI

My achievement

1. One-to-One call working fine

My issues :-

I need to implement  add new buddy feature so that we can do conference .

Whats My problems

1. I am unable to get conference  Voice call . scenarios is A called to B voice working fine ,but when B add new buddy  C then  B and C communicate but A and C Unable to communicate .

This my code which   i am using for calling  One-toOne

```
if (([[_label text] length] > 0) &&
                ([phoneCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialup:number:)]))
            {
                _lastNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [_label text]];
                [_label setText:@""];
            }
            else
            {
                _lcd.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lcd_top_simple.png"]];
                [_label setText:_lastNumber];
                [_lastNumber release];
            }

        }

Call.m file  calling this below method . 

status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id);
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
  {
    pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error making call", status);
  }
```

Comment: Is this question about programming? If you have a problem to download a file from google server, you should ask google where the file is.

Comment: Try to remove ´<>´ and to put ´""´

Comment: this a programming questions (objective-c) ,i am getting  preference.framework   framework empty thats why error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing some files Which is from "PJSIP" library. Please include the "PJSIP" library after compilation, or you may download the project from this [link](https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles), this project have compiled "PJSIP" included.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;
  SiphonApplication *app = (SiphonApplication *)[SiphonApplication sharedApplication];

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
//    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE,"on_call_media_state status %d count %d",
//      ci.media_status
//      pjmedia_conf_get_connect_count()));

  /* FIXME: Stop ringback */
  sip_ring_stop([app pjsipConfig]); 

  /* Connect ports appropriately when media status is ACTIVE or REMOTE HOLD,
   * otherwise we should NOT connect the ports.
   */
  if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
      ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD) 
  {
    // When media is active, connect call to sound device.
    pjsua_conf_connect(ci.conf_slot, 0);
    pjsua_conf_connect(0, ci.conf_slot);

    //pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level(0, 3.0);
    //pjsua_conf_adjust_tx_level(0, 5.0);
  }


    if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) { //    When media is active, connect call to sound device.
        pjsua_conf_port_id slotOne = ci.conf_slot;
        //        pjsua_conf_connect(slotOne, 0);
        //        pjsua_conf_connect(0, slotOne);
        //mergeCalls=true;


        int max=pjsua_call_get_count();
        if (max==2) {
            mergeCalls=true;
        }

        if (mergeCalls == true) {
            pjsua_conf_port_id slotTwo = pjsua_call_get_conf_port(activeCallID);
            pjsua_conf_connect(slotOne, slotTwo);
            pjsua_conf_connect(slotTwo, slotOne);

            // since the "activeCallID" is already  talking, its conf_port is already connected to "0" (and vice versa) ...

        } else {
            activeCallID = call_id;
        }
    } else if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_LOCAL_HOLD) {
        // … callSuspended(callID);
    }

}
```